# How to limit the number of tags the user can put into the input field?

Tags: bootstrap-tags-input

For example, if I want to limit the number of tags the user can put in to 1 (so the user can put in only 1 tag) in a tagsinput, how can I do it?

I want it to act more like the "limit" parameters in textarea so the user isn't allow to put in more than 1 tag in the space of the input.

Reference:
http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on their documentation, you will need to initialize the code by setting the `maxTags` property value to 1.

```
$('input').tagsinput({
  maxTags: 1
});
```